# Problems linking to FFMPEG library in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mingw32

I have cross-compiled FFMPEG from Debian using the mingw32 toolchain. The result of the compilation is a set of **.a** files. When I try to use them in my project I get linker errors, concretely the following ones:

```
1>RTSPCapture.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _avformat_free_context referenced in function ...
1>RTSPCapture.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _avio_close referenced in function ...
1>RTSPCapture.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _avcodec_close referenced in function ...
(and much more...)
```

I have already included the header files like this:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavformat/avio.h>
}
```

And I use the .a files like this:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libavcodec.a")
#pragma comment(lib, "libavformat.a")
#pragma comment(lib, "libavutil.a")
```

May I know why I am still getting linker errors? Best regards,

**EDIT:** I have realized that this is not possible. So, what should I do to use FFMPEG library in my MSVC2010 project taking into account that I can't compile ffmpeg in Windows? it seems to be REALLY difficult...

Comment: You might want to read [this link](http://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b-or-Intel-C_002b_002b-Compiler-for-Windows).

Comment: Or why not simply [download the Windows files already compiled](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)?

Comment: I need to compile it by myself to debug it and I need also to use the static libraries instead of the dynamic.

Comment: Then read my first link, on how to build for MSVC.

Comment: This is a very bad idea to compile ffmpeg under MSVC. Instead of cross-compilation, try msys + mingw32 under windows (I use this way in my projects)

Comment: Okay, but, in the end, the resulting libraries will not work with my applications that are compiled using MSVC2010, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I realized that mingw compiles libs could not be linked in VS2010 native applications.

Answer (score 2):

GCC (the compiler used by MinGW) does not have the `#pragma` used by VisualC++ to add libraries. You have to manually add the libraries when linking using the `-l` option:

```
$ gcc objectfile1.o objectfile2.o -o executable -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me apologize but I don't understand this. I have successfully compiled ffmpeg from Debian, and what I am trying to do is to use that resulting .a files in my MSVC2010 project that I am trying to compile in VS2010 in Windows. Where I have to use gcc ?

Comment: @DídacPérez Oh, so you want to use library files compiled using MinGW in VC++? Then that's not possible. The library formats are not compatible.

Comment: Joachim, OK. That's what I have read... :( WELL, let me ask you another question, I will edit my question in 1 min.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's not true. For C (not C++) library format is compatible.

Comment: @DídacPérez Try to link with the libs from here: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ (dev package)